# Charts - OOo basic: how to display percentages in a PieChart

Tags: charts, pie-chart, openoffice.org, basic, openoffice-basic

I am writing a macro to generate pie chart in OpenOffice Basic and I want to display the percentage of the different parts on the graph. For example, I want a result as in the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/display-percentage-values-on-a-pie-chart-report-builder-and-ssrs

Here is my reproducible code:

my data are:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwdDz.png

And the Macro:

```
Sub Macro1

 Dim oRange as Object
 Dim oRangeAddress(1) As New com.sun.star.table.CellRangeAddress
 Dim oRect As New com.sun.star.awt.Rectangle
 Dim cTitle as String

oRange = thisComponent.getCurrentSelection.getRangeAddress
oSheets = ThisComponent.getSheets()
oSheet = oSheets.getByIndex(0)
oCharts = oSheet.Charts

oRect.Width = 10000
oRect.Height = 10000
oRect.X = 8000
oRect.Y = 1000

oRangeAddress(0).Sheet = oRange.Sheet
oRangeAddress(0).StartColumn = 0
oRangeAddress(0).StartRow = 0
oRangeAddress(0).EndColumn = 1
oRangeAddress(0).EndRow = 2

cTitle = "Test Results"
oCharts.addNewByName(cTitle,oRect,oRangeAddress(),TRUE, TRUE)
oChart = oCharts.getByName(cTitle).embeddedObject
oChart.Diagram = oChart.createInstance("com.sun.star.chart.PieDiagram")
oChart.HasMainTitle = True
oChart.Title.String = cTitle

End Sub
```

Thank you a lot for your help! I find the documentation for OOo basic very difficult to understand and rather poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=44377, I eventually came up with this code that does what you need.

```vb
rowProps = oChart.Diagram.getDataRowProperties(0)
rowProps.DataCaption = com.sun.star.chart.ChartDataCaption.PERCENT
Dim oLocale As New com.sun.star.lang.Locale
rowProps.PercentageNumberFormat = ThisComponent.getNumberFormats().queryKey(_
   "0%", oLocale, True)
```

Documentation on number formats, such as there is, can be found at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OfficeDev/Managing_Number_Formats.  Many common tasks in Basic are pretty well documented, but what you are doing is somewhat unusual, hence the rather obscure documentation.

Feel free to keep asking for help -- your questions have been well written.  With practice, working with the UNO API becomes easier.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I need!